# ProGuard - unexpectedly contains class

Tags: class, warnings, obfuscation, proguard

While I'm trying to obfuscate simple DataLoader.class file in ProGuard I get this error:

```
Reading program directory [C:\Users\uzytkownik\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProTest\build\classes\Files\DataLoader.class]
Warning: class [DataLoader.class] unexpectedly contains class [Files.DataLoader]
Warning: there were 1 classes in incorrectly named files.
         You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
         The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
         If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
         you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Here is the project:
http://www49.zippyshare.com/v/14668241/file.html

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the options `-injars` and `-libraryjars`, you should specify the proper base directory (or jar) of your classes, just like a classpath. In this case: `classes`, not `classes\Files\DataLoader.class`.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: class file ... unexpectedly contains class ...](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unexpectedclass)

Comment: can you provide an example of `-injars` with the proper base directory and input jar? I haven't found any example when looking into the docs

Answer (score 13):

```
Warning: class [META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class] unexpectedly contains class [module-info]
```

This is the issue I had and I tried few options mentioned below:

1. -keep class module-info
2. -keepattributes Module*
3. -dontwarn module-info

The option worked for me is 3.

Not sure why but it solves my problem and I am able to make the jar.

This issue comes when you upgrade something like I upgrade the spring-boot version and the project starts failing.

Please check the maven dependencies as well.

Comment: Thanks, the 3rd option works for me (to be checked if there is side effect, though).