# Upgrade to Kotlin 1.4 get error compiler about module-info.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin version 1.3.7 . So when I upgrade to 1.4.10 I get the compiler error

```
Cause: cannot find META-INF.versions.9.module-info: module-info found in META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class
```

Is there any help?

Comment: I've added a link, this might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60646464/10002974

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code inside `android` block which is present in your app-level gradle file.

```
android 
{
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }
}
```